# Find and Replace emojis in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

When I export my Google Sheets to a third party app that crunches the data, it will always spit out an error code if my written content has emojis (which it often does, due to the nature of the content). Other icons like ► are fine. It's just emojis: The app isn't coded to parse them!

Basically—if it's an emoji, I want to be able to identify and delete it. RegExtract [isn't working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lp8R.png) Any ideas? Manually deleting isn't that time-consuming, but it's annoying. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try regexreplace. For example this will remove emoji in column A:

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(A2:A,"[\x{1F300}-\x{1F64F}]|[\x{2702}-\x{27B0}]|[\x{1F68}-\x{1F6C}]|[\x{1F30}-\x{1F70}]|[\x{2600}-\x{26ff}]|[\x{D83C}-\x{DBFF}\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}]",""))
```

Comment: This is working—but it's also getting rid of quotes, hashtags, and other things! Any other parameters I can add?

Comment: working like a charm, you beautiful person! thank you!

Comment: my friend: last question! is there a way to add exceptions at will? for example, i may not want to delete 22C6.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the question. Can you provide an example?

Comment: i can rephrase: if i wanted to keep (as in, not delete) specific icons like ★, is there a way to specify that? currently, ★ is being deleted, but i don't think it's an emoji.

Comment: ★ is is unicode 2605. By changing [\x{2600}-\x{26ff}] to [\x{2606}-\x{26ff}] in the formula it will keep the ★. Check out unicode characters and regex.

Comment: thank you for everything - it's so, so appreciated. if there is a way to thank you please tell me it. i am still wondering how to single out exceptions without changing the ranges you've provided - how does the code look with an exception added to this regexreplace formula?

Comment: I think it can be done. I just don't know how to do it. You should ask another question showing what you have so far and what you want to have as a result.