# How Search and Find Emojis on Sheets

Tags: regex, twitter, google-sheets, text-mining, re2

I'm working on a Sheets spreadsheet with thousands of tweets, and I need to find a regex or a formula that allows me to tell whether a cell contains emojis.

I've found the below regex on a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501740/find-and-replace-emojis-in-google-sheets/53882786?noredirect=1#comment94612239_53882786), which does a great job at removing emojis; however, some emojis still make through (I guess because they are new) namely, ‍️ and a few more. Could someone suggest an amendement to the expression?

Thanks!

> =arrayformula(regexreplace(A2:A,"[\x{1F300}-\x{1F64F}]|[\x{2702}-\x{27B0}]|[\x{1F68}-\x{1F6C}]|[\x{1F30}-\x{1F70}]|[\x{2600}-\x{26ff}]|[\x{D83C}-\x{DBFF}\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}]",""))

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth trying:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(A2:A,"[^[:ascii:]]",))
```

but difficult to say without input/output samples.

Comment: This definitely worked with the emojis, but it also got rid of other characters that should not disappear such as vowels with the Spanish accent (á, é, etc.) Any suggestions?